# Metodo Construtor não funciona (POO PHP)

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, método

Estou iniciando meus estudo em POO no PHP estava estudando método construtor, então eu criei uma classe Pessoa com os atributos "nome" e "idade", com o método construtor, e criei um método pra escrever os atributos

O problema é que quando instancio um objeto e passo os parâmetros do método construtor e chamo o método para escrever os atributos, os mesmo não aparecem. irei deixar o código para vocês entenderem melhor.

```
<?php

class Pessoa{

    var $nome;
    var $idade;

    function Pessoa($no,$age){

        $this->nome=$no;
        $this->idade=$age;
    }

    function escreve(){
        echo "Nome: ".$this->nome."<br>";
        echo "Idade: ".$this->idade."<br>";
    }
}

 $pessoa1=new Pessoa("João Vitor",28);

 $pessoa1->escreve();
```

Answer (score 0):

O método construtor no php não é assim, é uma função chamada `__construct`:

```
public function __construct($no,$age){
    // etc, etc
}
```

Métodos construtores com o nome da Classe são *deprecated*.

Comment: Ahhhh, muito obrigado sério, to até envergonhado de mim mesmo de ter errado algo tão simples haha

Comment: De nada! Se a resposta serviu, por favor aceite, me dá uns pontos aqui no Stack :-)